# Generic interfaces in Java

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have the following interfaces

```
public interface Group {
    public Group add(Group g);
    public Group sub(Group g);
    public Group getAddInv();
    public boolean isZero();
}

public interface Ring extends Group {
    public Ring mul(Ring r);
    public boolean isOne();
}
```

I now want to make these interfaces generic to make sure the methods can only be called for elements of the same algebraic structure.

For example it should be possible to add two elements of Ring but not to add one Element of Group and one element of Ring.

My first thought was using < ? super Ring > for the methods of Group, but that didn't work out. How can i achieve this?

Update:

```
public interface Group<T> {
    public T add(T g);
    public T sub(T g);
    public T getAddInv();
    public boolean isZero();
}

public interface Ring<T> extends Group<Ring<T>> {
    public T mul(T r);
    public boolean isOne();
}
```

Would that be a solution?

Comment: By the way, are you defining interfaces for the whole sets, or just for their elements? I don't think you want to make a [direct] sum of tho whole groups, but better the result of the binary operation, as a single element of the set - am I right?

Comment: The interfaces define single elements. It is a excersice i have to solve for programming class - and its instructions are terrible...

Comment: My maths are quite rusty, but I think a Ring is not a Group. R, for instance, is not a group because of 0, and R* is not a Ring because of... 0. This kind of violates the OO principle : a subclass object must be a superclass object

Comment: In fact what he's asking for *is* a violation of the Liskov substitution principle. Ring should probably not extend Group.

Comment: @Lorunification so you'd better call them `GroupElement` and `RingElement`, or define your methods like `public GroupElement add(GroupElement a, GroupElement b)` ^^.

Comment: @Jerome Actually, a ring *is* a group. That's not the problem here. The problem is that he wants to check values via the type system. That don't work.

Comment: As i already mentioned these interfaces were given in the instructions from my excersice - it took me quite a little to figure out that the names are just plain wrong. And the instructions say to solve this via the typesystem. I updated the question to what i now have done. I am not quite sure if this will work.

Comment: @Jerome yeah, a ring is a (R,+,\*) structure where (R,+) is an _abelian group_ and (R,\*) just a _semigroup_, so plain interface inheritance kinda sucks at dealing with them.

Comment: @Jochen _italic_ does not make a statement true. Demonstration or references does. R is indeed a group for addition. I got confused, a ring does not need group for multiplication, only for addition http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)

Comment: Well a ring is not a group because a group is a *couple* [set, op], and a ring is a *triple* [set, op1, op2] : P It kind of "holds" a group inside, but isn't formally. /me loves getting picky on algebraic defs.

Comment: Well as it seems this exersice is just plain nonsense. After a little talk with the guy that created this task we both came to the conclusion that he spoiled it.

Answer (score 4):

It should be like this:

```
public interface Group<T> {
    public T add(T g);
    public T sub(T g);
    public T getAddInv();
    public boolean isZero();
}

public interface Ring<T> extends Group<T> {
    public T mul(T r);
    public boolean isOne();
}
```

Actual implementations would implement these interfaces with a type parameter of themselves:

```
class MyInteger implements Ring<MyInteger>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe do you want to use such an interface:

```
public interface Test<T> {
    public void add(T t);
}
```

And then if you want you can use instanceof in you functions ?

Answer (score 1):

I would not try to do this via the type system. First, as some comments already mentioned, the interface seems rather odd (what does adding one group to another mean?).
Instead I'd focus on what is usually done on a group, which would like this

```
interface Group<T>{
  T add(T e1, T e2);  //adds two elements of the group and returns the result
  //sub is not a group operation, there is normally only one op
  ...
}
```

The same for the Ring, but add the `mul()` operation.

If you want to enforce that only elements that are contained within the group/ring can be used in operations, you implementation should check if the args are in the group/ring and throw an exception if not. The the type system is *not* designed to do this, as this is a value based check, not a type check.

Comment: Obviously you have to add `T getAddInv(T)` for additive inverse and `T zero()` for the null element. I think your idea is totally sound.

Comment: Of course. My point was that the operation needs to operate on elements of the group, not on different groups. If the poor guy got those interfaces from the instructor, he's screwed anyway.